# Read specific word from text file in C# windows application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to read specific word from text file I know its easy and I have done but I need to read from sentence i.e. if file contain
WC|110916|F-12003||ZET5.4|27019570 then i need to pic "27019570" this specific word, I did with substring(26,8) splitting  with characters and its works but every line not having specific size/length so splitting words is not proper solution for this.
In short I need to know how do i check (|) this character and its position on every sentence which includes in text file.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: is there multi line sentences in your text file?

Comment: yes, but now problem solved thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split each line by '|' character . it returns an array then you can select the desired index.

```
var textFromFile = "WC|110916|F-12003||ZET5.4|27019570";
var goalText = textFromFile.Split('|')[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, it's easy using LINQ with `File.ReadAllLines`

```
string fullFilePath = @"C:\ed\cc\filename.txt";

List<string> items = File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath ).Select(line=>line.Split('|').Last()).ToList();
```